# phpexcel class adding single inverted comma in datetime field

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using phpexcel class for adding my data to excel.

My field is 2015-05-05 34:23:45 it shows '2015-05-05 34:23:45 in excel.

Can anyone have idea, why ? All cell data showing perfect while echo. but when writes to excel it adds single inverted comma.

Can anyone have idea, why ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 34:23:45 : which format is this in? I don't think this is HH:mm:ss, perhaps you need to tell Excel if the format is different.

Comment: Also, to help others give you concrete answers, can you please showcase your code snippet/sample? Refer to this link for some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have downloaded code from here - https://github.com/newgrounds/Gen-Excel/tree/master/php-excel-v1.1-20090910 now in test.php file replace $data array as $data = array(
        1 => array ('a11', 'a12', 'a13'),
        array('2016-02-05 16:34:39', '80.179.122.138:5060', '--'),
        array('2016-02-12 16:34:39', '80.179.122.138:5060', '--')
        ); and see excel file 2016-02-05 16:34:39 => '2016-02-05 16:34:39. Got me ?